# How can I execute a command in a shell script in a loop and in background mode?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, background-process, mplayer

In [Restart mplayer stream process on loss of internet connection -> use while true](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40660/146500) an answer is given to restart an external command of a shell script - [mplayer](https://mplayerhq.hu/) - after a connection loss. One commentator also mentions that this solution does avoid high cpu usage - in contrast to this answer: [Restart mplayer stream process on loss of internet connection -> use -loop 0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66138/146500)

I want to extend this script [record.sh that calls mplayer as background job via '&'](https://github.com/m-ringler/hspiel/blob/ab17daa56431f9249546c626cb65ba3720e27255/record.sh#L220) so that it is also inert against internet connection losses or router reconnects.

**As I am a beginner in shell scripting, I have difficulties to get a solution that uses something like**

```
while true
    do mplayer http://YOURSTREAMHERE:8000/playlist.m3u -cache 1024
    sleep 2
done
```

**in the context of that `record.sh` script (which calls `mplayer` as a background task via `&`).**

**How would a modified `record.sh` script look like that is inert to connection losses and does not use much CPU?**

Comment: External to what?

Comment: with "external" I mean the `mplayer` command

Comment: So external to the `mplayer` command. And you want to do that from withing the `mplayer`?

Comment: No, this is probably a misunderstanding. My scripts calls the external command `mplayer`.

Comment: I fixed your question, to the best of my understanding, based no your comment. If I messed up, then edit, and write clearly.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your edit.